# Extending core Laravel 5 functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The question is quite simple - is it possible to extend Laravel 5 functionality in any smart way or you need to copy sometimes a lot of code/classes just to achieve what you want.

Because it's quite broad, I'll give you 2 examples.

1) I would like to change urls for `edit` and `create` for `\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar`. At the moment the only way I found to achieve that is: extending main Illuminate `Application` to pass own `RoutingServiceProvider`, then extend `Router`, then extend `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` and finally in `bootstrap/app.php` use our extended Application class. Quite a lot of modifications just to change 2 lines. Many methods are in fact duplicated just to pass our custom class which code is exact the same except it uses class from other namespace

2) Other similar change - set custom paths for cached config - you need to again extend  `Application` to override method `getCachedConfigPath` and then make a change in `bootstrap/app.php`

So the question is - is it the way that some modifications need to be done or maybe the same (for example those 2 above) could be achieved somehow easier not extending core `Application` class and making so many changes?

Comment: I think if you are to customize/ extend Laravel that much then Laravel might not be your framework or may be it's a new feature or a fix that Laravel needs. Have you considered building your own bootstrap with Laravel and Symfony packages?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @astroanu - I don't think wanting to tweak a few things here and there is reason enough to throw away the entire framework and all of the other things it gives you. No framework can be all things to all people, so I think it's totally okay to make some changes here and there as needed. Just be sure you're clearly documenting them so a future developer who is familiar with Laravel "out-of-the-box" can understand where you've differed from the norm.

Comment: @JordanLev read my comment and note "if you are to customize/ extend Laravel THAT much"

Comment: @astroanu I think we agree in principle but differ on where to draw the line. To me, what the OP is wanting to do is *not* that much... it's just changing urls for edit and create methods in the Router, and setting some custom paths for cached config files. These seem like very small tweaks in relation to the overall architecture of Laravel, so I just don't think it's really "that much" to warrant throwing away the entire framework.

Comment: One step can be skipped by re-registering extended `RoutingServiceProvider` in `bootstrap/app.php` instead of modifying `Application` class.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to overwrite the core `ResourceRegistrar` by binding your own implementation to the service container:

```
$this->app->bind('\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar', function()
{
    return new MyResourceRegistrar();
});
```

Let `MyResourceRegistrar` extend the core `ResourceRegistrar` and you should be able to overwrite the `edit` and `create` methods:

```
class MyResourceRegistrar extends \Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar
{
    // Overwrite your methods here
}
```